# let или this в объекте?

Tags: javascript

```
class Game {
    constructor(parentElement) {
        let wrap = document.createElement('div');
        wrap.className = 'wrap';
        parentElement.appendChild(wrap);

        this.nav = document.createElement('div');
        this.nav.className = 'nav';
        wrap.appendChild(this.nav);

        this.x = document.createElement('div');
        this.x.className = 'x';
        this.x.innerHTML = 'win x:'
        this.nav.appendChild(this.x);

        this.btn = document.createElement('button');
        this.btn.className = 'reset';
        this.btn.innerHTML = 'reset';
        this.nav.appendChild(this.btn);        

        this.o = document.createElement('div');
        this.o.className = 'o';
        this.o.innerHTML ='win o:'
        this.nav.appendChild(this.o);

        this.field = document.createElement('div');
        this.field.className = 'field';
        wrap.appendChild(this.field);

        // this.field = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            this.cell = document.createElement('div');
            this.cell.className = 'cell';
            this.field.appendChild(this.cell);
        }
        console.log(this.field.length)


    }

}
```

в классе Game я создаю каркас html для мини игры. Вопрос: все "переменные" (this.x , this.nav, this.btn) я бы мог создать через let - как первую (wrap).
В чем существенное отличие ???
не судите если это банально просто) я только изучаю js и бороду еще не отрастил)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь `wrap` - локальная переменная в конструкторе:

```
   let wrap = document.createElement('div');
```

Здесь `wrap` - свойство создаваемого объекта:

```
   this.wrap = document.createElement('div');
```

Если ссылка нужна только внутри функции, используйте локальную переменную. Если ссылка на объект нужна в других методах или во внешнем коде, используйте свойство объекта.

Присваивание `this.cell = ...` в цикле - бессмысленно.

Comment: _______спасибо!